# Mysql: select value that matches several criteria on multiple rows

Tags: mysql, join

Good evening,

I have two tables t1 and t2

In t1, I have two variables, ID (which uniquely identify each row) and DOC (which can be common to several IDs)

In t2, I have three variables, ID (which does not necessarily uniquely identify the rows here), AUTH , and TYPE. Each ID has a maximum of 1 distinct AUTH.

Sample data:

[image]

What I would like to do is to select the DOCs that have an ID with AUTH='EP', and that also have an ID with AUTH='US'. They could have additional IDs with other AUTH, but they have to have at least these two.

Thus, i would have a final table with the DOC, ID,and AUTH (there should be at least 2 IDs per doc, but it can be more if there exists an additional AUTH to US and EP for this DOC)

The desired results:

[image]

Comment: How come the desired result has ID 5. How does it satisfy the above condition?

Comment: Because ID 5 is part of DOC B, which satisfies the condition thanks to ID 3 and to ID 4.

Comment: Got it. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (T1.ID), T1.DOC, T2.AUTH FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID 
WHERE T1.DOC IN( SELECT T1.DOC FROM T2 
               LEFT JOIN T1 ON T1.ID = T2.ID  
               WHERE T2.AUTH IN('EP','US') 
               GROUP BY T1.DOC HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT T2.AUTH) = 2) ;
```

Comment: It seems to work ! Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.I am glad it work for you.Whenever any answer work for you make sure to mark as the correct answer. Learn more here http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Done ! I am novice in sql so I have two questions regardind the code :
- Why do you put (T1.ID) between parenthesis in the first line ? 
- Do you know how I could had a column with the count of _AUTH_ per _DOC_ ? So that, in the results table above, this column would be :
**2**
**2**
**3**
**3**
**3**

I know how to do it in stata but it would be nice to learn a bit more of sql  ! Thanks again

Comment: I could also write SELECT DISTINCT T1.ID, it would make no difference, Using group by clause you could get the count of AUTH per DOC. try first and share your code and we shall help you to solve the problem.

Comment: ok I just shared it as an aswer because it was too long for a comment

Answer (score 0):

If I could understand correctly the query is going to be something like that:

```
select t1.doc, t1.id, t2.auth from t1
left join t2 on t2.id = t1.id
where t1.doc in( select t1.doc from t2
                 left join t1 on t1.id = t2.id
                 where t2.auth in('EP','US') );
```

Although, the result set is basically going to be the first sample data table, due to the **ID 6** which has a **AUTH = "EP"** and, consequently, the **ID 7** which has the same **DOC** from **ID 6**.